# Creating static library using only one .h file for iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, static-libraries

I created static library which have many .h files. I want to create library that contains only one .h files which include all other .h files. But when I try to create such library it gives me " .h files not found " error.

Can any one know how to create such library? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

create a .m (or .mm) file, include your .h file, and compile the .m file instead of the .h file.

BTW, why you want to build library from .h file?? .h file should not contain any implementation. the exception is C++ templates and inline functions, then you will not build anything without instantiate the template